# Automatic login to Facebook with cron/cURL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, cron

I've seen so many solutions for this but haven't been able to implement any of them sucessfully. I have created an App in Facebook and can successfully use FQL to retrieve data. I will be pulling in event information from pages and groups that I am part of. I will only parse the event information of those who explicitly register with my App/website.

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK. The issue is that I want to create a cron task to retrieve event information periodically, but I don't know how to allow the cron task to log in automatically.

I've seen that there are real-time updates, but as far as I know, they don't show events.

I tried to use cURL but it just brought up a blank screen. The code was:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'facebook_cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'facebook_cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$email = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email='.urlencode($email).'&     
     pass='.urlencode($pass).'&login=Login');

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
```

That was taken from another SO question: [Remote login to facebook account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130449/remote-login-to-facebook-account)

Comment: Maybe you don't need to log, app access_token can't solve your problem?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

Comment: Don’t scrape Facebook’s pages, use the Graph API to get information.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro: Thanks for the link. I missed that. I'm still unsure if that will allow me to gain access to events: "While an App Access Token is largely for the purposes of publishing information back to Facebook on behalf of the user, there is a limited set of information that can be retrieved from Facebook using an App Access Token.Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender); A User’s Friends and their IDs; Permissions granted by the User to your App". I'm still trying to wrap my head around their terminology.

Comment: @CBroe: When I said "parse", I actually meant that I'll be using their Graph API or their FQL.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro: can you please write your comment in the form of a question so that I can mark it as the correct answer? I used the App access token without the need to log in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you don't need to log, app [access_token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens) can't solve your problem?